# ERROR: can't locate node in package [gazebo_ros]

Tags: gazebo, urdf, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello~ I'm new in ROS and am learning it by the tutorials.However,there were some errors when I followed the  [Tutorial: Using a URDF in Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf).
Everthing is normal until I ran the the command:

```
roslaunch rrbot_gazebo rrbot_world.launch
```

[image: image description]

However, it seems I can start gazebo  by command line.
[image: image description]

I have tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-indigo-gazebo-ros`,but it didn't work.

This is all the files I have in `/opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/`.Is there anything wrong?

[image: image description]

Thanks a lot for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262907/error:-can%27t-locate-node-in-package--%5Bgazebo_ros%5D/) by [Richardaria](https://answers.ros.org/users/30329/richardaria/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-05-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-05-31**:
How did you install `gazebo_ros` -- from source or from apt-get? What does `rospack find gazebo_ros` return?

**Comment by [Richardaria](https://answers.ros.org/users/30329/richardaria/) on 2017-05-31**:
It returns this:
/opt/ros/indigo/share/gazebo_ros

Should I reinstall Gazebo?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-05-31**:
You could certainly try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-indigo-gazebo-ros` although, that wouldn't explain what went wrong in the first place. Do you have the missing executables in `/opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/` (that's where they should get installed)?

**Comment by [Richardaria](https://answers.ros.org/users/30329/richardaria/) on 2017-05-31**:
I tried   `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-indigo-gazebo-ros`  .However,the same problem still exist.
I have attached a screenshot of all the files I got in /opt/ros/indigo/lib/ga zebo_ros/. Is there any problem?
Thanks for your help!

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-06-01**:
If that works, then there is likely something wrong with your workspace. Try deleting the build/ and devel/ directories and then re-running `catkin_make`

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-06-01**:
Also, as a side note, please stop posting images to show information that is fundamentally text (list files in a directory, error messages, terminal commands, etc.). Images are not searchable nor are they copy/paste-able. Please post this type of thing using the preformatted text button.

**Comment by [Richardaria](https://answers.ros.org/users/30329/richardaria/) on 2017-06-01**:
It works just as you said.Thanks a lot. It seems that I have installed gazebo twice.I'm not very familiar with the editor of this website, learning and improving. Thanks for you advice.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-06-02**:
Is your original question resolved? Can you now run your rrobt launch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you maybe have an additional copy of `gazebo_ros` in your workspace? Try using rosrun to manually start one of the missing nodes: (i) start `roscore` (ii) `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` to use just the base install (deactivates your workspace)  (iii) `rosrun gazebo_ros gzserver`

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this issue by these steps:

1. delete build and devel folders.
2. catkin_make.

---

Originally posted by [lyz](https://answers.ros.org/users/39705/lyz/) with karma: 11 on 2019-01-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This worked for me:-

sudo chmod +x /file path*(gzserver)

sudo chmod +x /file path*(gzclient)

sudo chmod +x /file path*(spawn_model)

*means location where the files are present

for eg:/home/tom/project_ws/src/gazebo_ros/gazebo_ros/scripts/gzclient

---

Originally posted by [harrynick](https://answers.ros.org/users/44792/harrynick/) with karma: 23 on 2020-01-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeremy_Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/101752/jeremy_liu/) on 2022-04-11**:
This works for me, too. Thanks!

**Comment by [Hector P](https://answers.ros.org/users/134728/hector-p/) on 2023-01-19**:
This works for me, too. Ty!